# support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled laravel 8

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am using react js in laravel 8 and I want to use it by installing it through npm without using laravel ui and I got this error

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this issue, and I don't think it matters which version of laravel is running (i.e. 7 or 8). First, check in package.json that you have version 5 of laravel-mix. If you do, you need version 6+, which can be achieved by the following:

1. Install the latest version from npm with `npm i -D laravel-mix@latest`.
2. Verify the entry in package.json has "^6.0.9" or something that starts with 6 or higher.
3. Copy the below code and paste over the mix.js entry in webpack.mix.js.

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .react();
```

4. Run `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` to see laravel-mix install correct babel dev dependencies and build.

Note: I'm adding to the mix.js instead of creating a new one because I am not using .jsx files. If you are, then add a new entry in webpack.mix.js with the below.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.jsx', 'public/js')
   .react();
```

Source: [Laravel Mix React Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#React) and my hard-headedness.

Full example of possibilities for your question in webpack.mix.js. If you're using jsx, get rid of the .react() in the first mix.js call and uncomment the second mix.js.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .react();

// mix.js('resources/js/app.jsx', 'public/js')
//     .react();
```

As I'm a new contributor, if the answer is acceptable, please accept it.